# How to run BPMN2 in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, bpmn

I have installed BPMN2 Modeler in Eclipse, but when I try to run it, nothing happens (it stays on java interface). I go to `project - general project`. From here, it stays on java interface, instead on modeling interface.

How to run BPMN2 in Eclipse?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run a bpmn process in eclipse. You need to generate a deployable artifact and deploy it in a BPMN engine. Follow [1] on how it can be done using WSO2's eclipse based tooling - Developer studio and deploy in the enterprise integrator bps profile.

[1] - https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/Creating+a+BPMN+Process